# Merge Sort in a data store?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to make a "friend stream" for the project I'm working on. I have individual users streams saved in Redis ZSETS. Something like:

```
key : { stream_id : time }
user1-stream: { 1:9931112, 3:93291, 9:9181273, ...}
user2-stream: { 4:4239191, 2:92919, 7:3293021, ...}
user3-stream: { 8:3299213, 5:97313, 6:7919921, ...}
...

user4-friends: [1,2,3]
```

Right now, to make user4's friend stream, I would call:

```
ZUNIONSTORE user4-friend-stream, [user1-stream, user2-stream, user3-stream]
```

However, ZUNIONSTORE is slow when you try to merge ZSETS totaling more than 1-2000 elements.

I'd really love to have Redis do a merge sort on the ZSETS, and limit the results to a few hundred elements. Are there any off-the-shelf data stores that will do what I want? If not, is there any kind of framework for developing redis-like data stores?

I suppose I could just fork Redis and add the function I need, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: hi @ABentSpoon, did you manage to do that in Lua? I should have EXACTLY the same problem as you, need to have a ZUNION with a limit using the weight as a stop condition to dig in each friend stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People tend to think that a zset is just a skip list. This is wrong. It is a skip list (ordered data structure) plus a non ordered dictionary (implemented as a hash table). The semantic of a merge operation would have to be defined. For instance, how would you merge non disjoint zsets whose common items do not have the same score?

To implement a merge algorithm for ZUNIONSTORE, you would have to get the items ordered (easy with the skip lists), merge them while building the output (which happens to be a zset as well: skiplist plus dictionary).

Because the cardinality of the result cannot be guessed at the beginning of the algorithm, I don't think it is possible to build this skiplist + dictionary in linear time. It will be O(n log n) at best. So the merge is linear, but building the output is not: it defeats the benefit of using a merge algorithm.

Now, if you want to implement a ZUNION (i.e. directly returning the result, not building the result as a zset), and limit the result to a given number of items, a merge algorithm makes sense.

RDBMS supporting merge joins can typically do it (but this is usually not very efficient, due to the cost of random I/Os). I'm not aware of a NoSQL store supporting similar capabilities.

To implement it in Redis, you could try a Lua server-side script, but it may be complex, and I think it will be efficient only if the zsets are much larger than the limit provided in the zunion. In that case, the limit on the number of items will offset the overhead of running interpreted Lua code.

The last possibility is to implement it in C in the Redis source code, which is not that difficult. The drawback is the burden to maintain a patch for the Redis versions you use. Redis itself provides no framework to do that, and the idea of defining Redis plugins (isolated from Redis source code) is generally rejected by the author.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered the non-disjoint case very thoroughly; sounds like I'll not be getting a patch in to Redis. I'll see if the Lua path is fast enough, and then see what I can do about a custom fork. I'd love to know how Facebook solves this.